# Do I need to dress with slacks and a button-down shirt for a job interview as a cashier?

Tags: interviewing

If not, what would be appropriate to wear to the interview?

Comment: Rule of thumb:  Always aim for overdressed rather than underdressed for an interview.

Comment: I wouldn't overdress for a cashier position, but a button-down shirt and slacks is business casual, so that's not overdressing.  You can also wear a "nice" shirt (doesn't have your favorite band's logo on it) and that would work for this situation.  I wouldn't wear anything below Khakis either, in fact take a look at how folks on the sales floor dress and match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only worked at one retail store my entire life so I'm not a expert at this. When I was 16-17, I worked as a cashier at a retail store and for the interview and first day of work, I wore a shirt and tie. I think a full suit is a bit overboard and maybe inappropriate but I think a nice pants and buttoned shirt with tie won't hurt.

Keep in mind though, 99% of their selection process goes with your availability. So if you aren't available during the times they need you, chances are they'll just pass.

Answer (score 13):

> If not, what would be appropriate to wear to the interview?

Your interview is about making a **good first impression**.

Your outfit, your hair, your clothing selection, it all matters.  While I don't think you need to wear a suite and tie, I think a pair of nice slacks and a pressed button up shirt is appropriate, based on my experience as a hiring manager.

As a matter of fact, as a younger man I interviewed for a grocery store bagger position and wore the same basic outfit.  Slacks and a button down shirt (for what its worth I got the job).

Answer (score 3):

I always go to an interview suited and booted. It puts me in the right frame of mind for the interview. Also you cannot go wrong being overdressed.

Comment: You can certainly go wrong for being overdressed, but it's a question of magnitude. If the OP showed up wearing a suit and tie to interview for a cashier position, that would reflect badly. A tuxedo or evening gown is overdressed for almost any position outside of special formal events.